# restarting rails app after deployment using mina

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment

I have successfully deployed my app using mina but after I try to deploy the changes I made, the old one is shown. How do I restart the rails app using mina?

Comment: try this in server terminal => touch tmp/restart.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to restart your passenger. For this run :

For passenger :

```
'passenger:restart'
```

You can write in your deployment script like below :

```
task deploy: :environment do
  deploy do
    # Put things that will set up an empty directory into a fully set-up
    # instance of your project.

    to :launch do
      invoke :'passenger:restart'
    end
  end
end
```